# Microsoft Bot Framework Teams Channel: Message Back Behavior for Notification Only Bots

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm troubleshooting an issue with my Microsoft Bot Framework chatbot using the Microsoft Teams channel.

I have configured the chatbot to be 'Notification Only' by setting the 'isNotificationOnly' = true within the app manifest.

I send users a Hero Card notification that contains 2 buttons of type = ActionTypes.MessageBack. The buttons will send a hidden value to the bot controller via the OnMessageActivityAsync method.

The implementation works when testing locally using the Bot Framework Emulator, but when testing on MS Teams channel I don't believe the OnMessageActivityAsync is being called due to the 'isNotificationOnly' property being enabled.

I want to better understand the behavior of the 'isNotificationOnly' property and how it impacts the available ActivityHandler methods.

Comment: If your bot's sole purpose is to deliver notification to users and isn't conversational, you can enable the `isNotificationOnly` field in your app manifest. This produces the following changes: -Users can't message your notification-only bot. - Users can't @mention the bot. Please refer below docs for more details:1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive?tabs=csharp 2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: I'm a bit confused... you're wanting the bot to NOT receive any user messages (hence `isNotificationOnly=true`, but then you're sending a card with a button, thus expecting to receive user messages. I think these are mutually exclusive, which is what's causing your issue.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thanks for the helpful documentation. 
@HiltonGiesenow I've just confirmed that your assumption is correct. My intent was to prevent users from typing any messages to the bot by disabling the chat input, which is what this configurations setting does. I'm using the `MessageBack` action type to send a hidden message back to the bot, but that is not possible with the `isNotificationOnly` enabled. Thanks for the guidance!